# Get the `rel` attribute value of the first element with class xxxxx

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok, I have a series of Unordered Lists on a page I am working on. The list items of each unordered list have a class name for use with some click events that I have done. Now I am trying to find the :first/first() element of a given class name. Problem is, :first/first() return undefined. I know first() you can't specify a selector other than the element type (yet), and when I try

```
$('.selectorname :first').attr('rel');
```

to get the rel value of that first one i still get undefined. So I'm a bit confused how to tackle this as its not working the way I had hoped.

***EDIT***
The HTML as per request:

```
<ul>
   <li class="selectorname" rel="something">Some Fun stuff..</li>
   <li class="selectorname" rel="something">Some Fun stuff..</li>
   <li class="selectorname" rel="something">Some Fun stuff..</li>
   <li class="selectorname" rel="something">Some Fun stuff..</li>
   <li class="selectorname" rel="something">Some Fun stuff..</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$('.selectorname:first').attr('rel');
```

No space.

Answer (score 2):

You can use :eq selector like;
var val = $('.selectorname:eq(0)').attr('rel');

This will select first element from all elements which has "selectorname" class. You can select second element by writing parameter 1 or  third element by write 2. Since you have 5 elements has class "selectorname" you can use :eq(0) to select first one of it here.

here: http://jsfiddle.net/6QxNb/3/

Comment: Justice Erolin, nailed it. when I accidentally left a space in the syntax and simply missed it in my review trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Justice's answer showed you the problem with `":first"`, but since you mentioned the `.first()` method this is how you'd use it:

```
$(".selectorname").first().attr("rel")
```